# Iterate a join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to iterate through one specific table. All the table has is a `Parent ID` and a `Child ID`. What I want is to select all children and then use those as a parent to select the next set of children. It is possible for a parent ID to be linked to multiple Children. all I know beforehand is the first parent ID.

This is what I tried:

```sql
DECLARE @Child AS int

SET @Child = 117019

WHILE @Child IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT
        @Child = adsa.FK_CHILDASSEMBLY
    FROM
        ASSEMBLYDETAILSUBASSEMBLY adsa
    WHERE
        adsa.FK_PARENTASSEMBLY = @Child

    PRINT @Child
END;
```

This just results in an infinite loop of the 1st child id but what I want is a full list of all the unique child ID's that are in some way linked to each other.

Comment: This sounds like a task for an rCTE. Sample data and expected results would help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a pretty simple recursive CTE:**

It's not clear what the foreign key is against, I have used `CHILDASSEMBLY_ID`

```sql
DECLARE @parent AS int = 117019;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        @parent CHILDASSEMBLY_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        adsa.CHILDASSEMBLY_ID
    FROM
        ASSEMBLYDETAILSUBASSEMBLY adsa
    JOIN
        cte ON cte.FK_CHILDASSEMBLY = adsa.CHILDASSEMBLY_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```